# Switched to PG! DB migration error: PG::ConnectionBad:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I was using sqlite but switched to pg  for some reasons.

I included pg gem in the makefile and made changes in the config/environments.

When I started migrating the data using ***rake db:migrate*** , I’m getting this error.

> PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory     Is the server running locally and accepting     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I've gone through all the posts related to this but did not find a solution.

I'm using **ruby 2.1.5** and **rails 4.2.0**.

Comment: Switching from SQLite to Postgres is like switching from a Matchbox car to a Bugatti.  You don't make those decisions *lightly*.  Now, are you sure that you have the server running?

Comment: I'm getting the same error after starting the server too.  But I was going through a couple of posts and  run this command 'postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres' . And now it says Fatal: User role 'sachilig' does not exist. Do  I need to create an Account and password ?

Comment: ...Yes.  Yes, you do.  Hence my car analogy earlier; SQLite is a flat-file database which doesn't use credentials, whereas Postgres absolutely *does* use credentials.

Comment: A somewhat common configuration that you might consider is using SQLite for development and Postgres for production.  That way, you don't get weighed down by the complexity of administering Postgres until you really need it.

Comment: @steveklein nonono, that way you fail to do all the important testing until you suddenly do it in production where there's the most chance of real harm caused by incompatibilities and problems. You also don't build experience with the system you're using in production in a safer environment. It's a *terrible* approach IMO. There's a reason that's not generally the recommended configuration anymore.

Comment: @Novice Are you on Mac OS X? If so, your Pg gem is linked to a different `libpq` than the PostgreSQL you are running. Specify `host: localhost` or `host: /tmp/` in your `database.yml`. That should've been one of the first search hits. Have you tried it? You say you've "gone through all the posts related to this" but you haven't said what you tried/investigated, what posts those were, etc.

Comment: I have been trying to install PG and create a Username and password but going through "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.3 : Depends: postgresql-client-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: postgresql-common (>= 142~) but it is not going to be installed"  Error @CraigRinger

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Can you post your `database.yml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start`

or

`sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

Both should work just fine

If you still get an error you should fix the **config/database.yml** file one way to go about this is simply create a new project

`rails new yourapp -d postgresql`

then just copy the **database.yml** file

if you need to create an new user and password

`sudo -u postgres createuser john -s`

If you would like to set a password for the user, you can do the following

`sudo -u postgres psql`

`postgres=# \password john`

Most of this is from gorails

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your PG server:

`$ postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html